# Is there an option to call method in mocked function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a method doing some check inside and if it's successfull I'm calling one method if failure I'm calling another one.
In unit tests, I'm mocking this method as I'm using 3rd party service. Is there any option in unittest mock to call the selected method that is inside the mocked method? Sorry, my description might be a bit messy but I believe code example will help :)
I have more than one 3rd_party_approves() methods so I can't just mock this one to return True/False

```
def fun(self):
    if 3rd_party_approves():  # Http request inside that I want to avoid in tests
        self.approve()
    else:
        self.reject()
```

I would like to be able to call reject() or approve methods in unit tests without making an HTTP request in 3rd_party_approves() method

Comment: How is it relevant that you have several 3rd_party_approves() methods? `fun()` is calling only one of them, why do you care about the others?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be making class method wrapper for `3rd_party_approves()`

```
class ProductionClass():
...
    def wrapper_for_3rd_party_approves(self):
        return 3rd_party_approves()
```

and mocking it with 
 **patch.object**

```
from unittest.mock import patch

with patch.object(ProductionClass, 'wrapper_for_3rd_party_approves', return_value=True):
    ProductionClass().fun() #will allow 3rd_party_approves and call self.approve()

with patch.object(ProductionClass, 'wrapper_for_3rd_party_approves', return_value=False):
    ProductionClass().fun() #will not allow 3rd_party_approves and call self.reject()
```